# recursion function recurring too often

Tags: python, recursion

Relatively early in my python journey and coding in general. I've come across an example question that asks that should flatten a list of lists. Now how many lists of lists exist I wouldn't know. Which leads me to doing my first recursion attempt:

```
array = [[1,2,3,['a','b','c'],4],'d', [5,6],[7],8,9]
flattened = []

def flattenme (iteritem):
    
    for item in iteritem:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) or isinstance(item, (str,bytes)):
            flattenme(item)
        else:
            flattened.append(item)
```

When I run this with

```
print(f"flatten method: {list(flattenme(array))}")
```

I get the error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Shouldn't

```
flattenme(item)
```

at the last time it's called just return the non-list item? I'm not sure what is going wrong and where my understanding of recursion is failing.

Comment: If the item is a string you should append it. not call the function again...

Comment: Strings produce smaller strings when iterated over. If you provide a string, then you'll never reach the "bottom". Python doesn't have a `char` type.

Comment: There are too many parentheses. The code does not run at all

Comment: `flattened` is not defined.

Comment: The method returns nothing, so you can't print it.

Comment: You only want to recurse on a string if you think `["foo"]` should flatten to `['f', 'o', 'o']`; in that case, you'll need to check not just  if `item` is a `str` value, but if its length is greater than one. (Without even getting into Unicode normalization issues, where `é` could be either a single composed character or an `e` followed by a composing accent character.)

Comment: I was suggested to change the recursive method call "flattenme(item)" to 
for deeper in flattenme(item):
                yield deeper
 but not sure why another for loop would be needed.

Comment: Why `or isinstance(item, (str,bytes))` ? Dont you just want to flatten lists ?

Comment: I'm assuming I would like to flatten dict's as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings and bytes are iterable. Specifically, strings yield strings of length 1 when iterated over.

This means your code recurses infinitely.

Furthermore, your function doesn't return anything.

Here is my suggestion, which makes `flattenme` a generator that doesn't split strings:

```
array = [[1,2,3,['a','b','c'],4],'d', [5,6],[7],8,9]

def flattenme (iteritem):
    for item in iteritem:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, (str,bytes)):
            yield from flattenme(item)
        else:
            yield item
```